# How to resolve to private IP of AWS EB Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, parse-server, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

A Parse Server is deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk behind an Application Load Balancer.

The EB environment URL is: `example.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`. An external CNAME record `parse.example.com` points to that environment URL.

Parse Server need to be configured with:

- `serverURL` (used internally for the server to call itself, e.g. cloud code)
- `publicServerURL` (used to compose URLs that are called by clients in public)

For `publicServerURL` it seems obvious to use `https://parse.example.com/parse` as clients in public will call this endpoint.

But `serverURL` needs to be set to a **private** URL, otherwise the server sends requests to itself via the Internet gateway which would incur *"data transfer out costs"* in AWS.

When I `eb ssh` into an EC2 instance both `parse.example.com` and `example.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` resolve to the **public** IP of the load balancer.

```
nslookup parse.example.com
Server:     172.31.0.2
Address:    172.31.0.2#53
Non-authoritative answer:
parse.example.com   canonical name = example.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com.
Name:   example.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
Address: 52.72.xxx.xxx
Name:   example.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
Address: 52.45.xxx.xxx

nslookup  example.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com 
Server:     172.31.0.2
Address:    172.31.0.2#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
Address: 52.72.xxx.xxx
Name:   example.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
Address: 52.45.xxx.xxx
```

So what has to be set for `serverURL` to make an internal call to a private IP?

Comment: Can you view the Load Balancer in the EC2 management console? If you obtain the DNS Name from there, it should resolve to a private IP address when resolved from _within_ the VPC.

Comment: Couldn’t the LB DNS name change? For example if I swap the URLs of two environments in EB.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - in my experience (and I've dug into this quite a bit), public ALB DNS names always resolve to public IPs, never private IPs (unlike the DNS name of an EC2 or RDS instance).

Comment: Alternatively I could use the EC2 instance private IP for when the server needs to call itself. But I can set that only once during parse server initialization in node.js. Would that IP ever change during an instance‘s lifetime?

Comment: Or could I add the EB to a VPC and set a static private IP?

Comment: I ended up setting `http://localhost/parse` for the server to call itself.

Comment: The IPs (it will have at least one IP for each availability zone) of AWS load balancers is subject to change at any time, and as such should not be relied upon. You should always use the DNS name.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting http://localhost/parse for the server to call itself - the obvious solution.